# Boost Spirit Implement small one-line DSL on a server application

Tags: c++, boost, dsl, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

Apologies if this question has been answered before.

I want to insert a small DSL into a server application I work on. The syntax is very simple and even at this early stage I am stumped. I just can't get my head around how to construct the syntax in spirit.

Here is an example of the syntax I want to test for:

```
WHERE [not] <condition> [ and | or <condition> ] <command> [parameters]
```

The WHERE clause will select a number of objects from an internal store by testing named properties on them. The vector of selected objects is then passed as input to the command object.

There are 2 possible tests I want to perform on each object:

```
<property> = "value"
```

and

```
<property> like <regexp>
```

There are 2 commands also:

```
print <propertyName> [, <propertyName> [...]]
```

and

```
set <propertyName> = "value" [, <propertyName> = "value" [...] ]
```

so examples of the syntax would be:

```
where currency like "GBP|USD" set logging = 1, logfile = "myfile"
```

and

```
where not status = "ok" print ident, errorMessage
```

I know this is a big ask, but I am wondering if there are any spirit experts out there who can knock out this syntax in a few seconds flat? I got as far as parsing LIKE and =, but got stuck when trying to mix that with AND, OR and NOT. The problem for me is not knowing where to start when thinking about how spirit will tackle this.

Comment: "apologies if this question has been answered before." - that seemed a bit ludicrous. However, for fun, I've written a sample that parses your grammar (and is able to print it out to check it)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See http://liveworkspace.org/code/3HUzjS for a proof of concept.

What I usually do first, is imagine how I'd like to store the parsed data.

### Data types

I like to stick to standard containers, `boost::variant` (and sometimes `boost::optional`). Read from the bottom up to see how simple it is, top-down:

```
struct regex {
    std::string _pattern;
    explicit regex(std::string const& pattern) : _pattern(pattern) {}
};

typedef boost::variant<double, int, std::string, regex> value;

enum logicOp { logicOr, logicAnd, logicPositive };

struct condition {
    bool          _negated;
    std::string   _propertyname;
    value         _operand;      // value or regex
};

struct filter {
    logicOp   _op;
    condition _cond;
};

struct setcommand {
    typedef std::list<std::pair<std::string, value> > pairs;
    pairs _propvals;
};

struct printcommand {
    std::vector<std::string> _propnames;
};

typedef boost::variant<printcommand, setcommand> command;

struct statement {
    std::vector<filter> _filters;
    command             _command;
};
```

Notes:

- I have, in this case, created a ADT for `regex` instead of requiring a switch on operator type (`=` vs. `like`) in the processing code.)
- I have assumed your values can be int, double, string (or regex with 'like').
- I have assumed you want left-to-right evaluation of the filter conditions (no precedence of `and` vs. `or`).
- I have **not** assumed that the arguments to a `set` or `print` command be unique.
- I've simplified the container for `filter` by giving the first item a 'no-op' logic combination.

### Grammar

With this target structure in place, writing the grammar becomes *relatively* straightforward:

```
using namespace qi;

// no-skipper rules
property_  = alpha >> *alnum;
strlit_    = '"' >> *(  (lit('\\') >> char_) | ~char_('"') ) > '"';

// with-skipper rules
regex_     = strlit_ [ _val = phx::construct<regex>(_1) ];
value_     = double_ | int_ | strlit_;
condition_ = (no_case["NOT"] >> attr(true) | attr(false)) 
    >> property_ 
    >> (
            no_case["LIKE"] >> regex_ | '=' >> value_
       );

print_   = no_case["PRINT"] >> property_ % ',';
set_     = no_case["SET"] >> (property_ >> '=' >> value_) % ',';
command_ = print_ | set_;

filters_ %= +(
        (
           no_case["WHERE"] [ _pass = (phx::size(_val) == 0) ] >> attr(logicPositive)
         | no_case["AND"]   [ _pass = (phx::size(_val) >  0) ] >> attr(logicAnd)
         | no_case["OR"]    [ _pass = (phx::size(_val) >  0) ] >> attr(logicOr)
        ) 
        >> condition_);

statement_ = filters_ >> command_;
```

Notes:

- I've decided that string should be able to contain quotes, so I made `\` an escape character
- the only 'tricky' business there is to make sure filter (conditions) starts with 'WHERE', and each subsequent condition *must* start with 'AND'/'OR'. It uses a semantic action

  ```
  [ _pass = (phx::size(_val) == 0) ]
  ```

  to check that the resulting list (`vector`) of filters is empty at that time during parsing
- the `attr(...)` idiom is used to get a default value for an optional keyword (`NOT`). The keyword is only optional in the grammar, not in the AST:

  ```
   no_case["NOT"] >> attr(true) | attr(false)
  ```

I have put together a demo, that prints the AST back using Spirit Karma. Note that I didn't make a lot of effort to make the syntax roundtrip:

1. `like` operators get printed as equality to regex (`m/.../`)
2. no escaping of special characters in string literals is done

#### Output of test program:

```
parse success: 'where currency like "GBP|USD" set logging = 1, logfile = "myfile"'
parsed: WHERE  currency = m/GBP|USD/ SET logging=1.0, logfile="myfile" 
parse success: 'where not status = "ok" print ident, errorMessage'
parsed: WHERE NOT status = "ok" PRINT ident, errorMessage 
parse success: 'where status = "ok" or not currency like "GBP|USD" print ident, errorMessage'
parsed: WHERE  status = "ok" OR NOT currency = m/GBP|USD/ PRINT ident, errorMessage 
parse success: 'where status = "\"special\"" set logfile = "C:\\path\\to\\logfile.txt"'
parsed: WHERE  status = ""special"" SET logfile="C:\path\to\logfile.txt"
```

### Full test program

Note: in addition to `parser` it also contains a `generator` to print the parsed AST data types back.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16f3ecb19a88e948)</kbd>**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;
namespace phx   = boost::phoenix;

struct regex
{
    std::string _pattern;
    explicit regex(std::string const& pattern) : _pattern(pattern) {}
};

typedef boost::variant<double, int, std::string, regex> value;

enum logicOp { logicOr, logicAnd, logicPositive };

struct condition
{
    bool          _negated;
    std::string   _propertyname;
    value         _operand;      // value or regex
};

struct filter
{
    logicOp   _op;
    condition _cond;
};

struct setcommand
{
    typedef std::list<std::pair<std::string, value> > pairs;
    pairs _propvals;
};

struct printcommand
{
    std::vector<std::string> _propnames;
};

typedef boost::variant<printcommand, setcommand> command;

struct statement
{
    std::vector<filter> _filters;
    command             _command;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(regex, (std::string, _pattern))
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(printcommand, (std::vector<std::string>, _propnames))
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(setcommand, (setcommand::pairs, _propvals))
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(condition, (bool, _negated)(std::string, _propertyname)(value, _operand))
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(filter, (logicOp, _op)(condition, _cond))
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(statement, (std::vector<filter>, _filters)(command, _command))

// see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14206443/85371
namespace boost { namespace phoenix { namespace stl {
    template <typename This, typename Key, typename Value, typename Compare, typename Allocator, typename Index>
        struct at_impl::result<This(std::map<Key,Value,Compare,Allocator>&, Index)>
        { typedef Value & type; };
    template <typename This, typename Key, typename Value, typename Compare, typename Allocator, typename Index>
        struct at_impl::result<This(std::map<Key,Value,Compare,Allocator> const&, Index)>
        { typedef Value const& type; };
}}}

template <typename It, typename Delim>
    struct generator : karma::grammar<It, statement(), Delim>
{
    generator() : generator::base_type(start)
    {
        using namespace karma;

        property_  = karma::string;
        strlit_    = '"'  << karma::string << '"';
        regex_     = "m/" << karma::string << "/";

        value_     = (double_ | int_ | strlit_ | regex_);
        negate_    = eps [ _pass = !_val ] | lit("NOT");

        condition_ = negate_  << property_  << '=' << value_;
        print_     = "PRINT " << property_ % ", ";
        set_       = "SET "   << (property_ << '=' << value_) % ", ";
        command_   = print_ | set_;

        static const auto logicOpNames = std::map<logicOp, std::string> { 
            { logicPositive, "WHERE" },
            { logicAnd, "AND" },
            { logicOr, "OR" } };

        logic_ = string [ _1 = phx::at(phx::cref(logicOpNames), _val) ];

        filters_ = +(logic_ << condition_);

        statement_ = filters_ << command_;

        start = statement_;
    }

  private:
    karma::rule<It, logicOp()            , Delim> logic_;
    karma::rule<It, statement()          , Delim> statement_;
    karma::rule<It, std::vector<filter>(), Delim> filters_;
    karma::rule<It, command()            , Delim> command_;
    karma::rule<It, condition()          , Delim> condition_;
    karma::rule<It, statement()          , Delim> start;
    karma::rule<It, bool()        > negate_;
    karma::rule<It, printcommand()> print_;
    karma::rule<It, setcommand()  > set_;
    karma::rule<It, std::string() > strlit_, property_;
    karma::rule<It, value()       > value_;
    karma::rule<It, regex()       > regex_;
};

template <typename It, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
    struct parser : qi::grammar<It, statement(), Skipper>
{
    parser() : parser::base_type(start)
    {
        using namespace qi;

        // no-skipper rules
        property_  = alpha >> *alnum;
        strlit_    = '"' >> *(  (lit('\\') >> char_) | ~char_('"') ) > '"';

        // with-skipper rules
        regex_     = strlit_ [ _val = phx::construct<regex>(_1) ];
        value_     = double_ | int_ | strlit_;
        condition_ = (no_case["NOT"] >> attr(true) | attr(false)) 
            >> property_ 
            >> (
                    no_case["LIKE"] >> regex_ | '=' >> value_
               );

        print_   = no_case["PRINT"] >> property_ % ',';
        set_     = no_case["SET"] >> (property_ >> '=' >> value_) % ',';
        command_ = print_ | set_;

        filters_ %= +(
                (
                   no_case["WHERE"] [ _pass = (phx::size(_val) == 0) ] >> attr(logicPositive)
                 | no_case["AND"]   [ _pass = (phx::size(_val) >  0) ] >> attr(logicAnd)
                 | no_case["OR"]    [ _pass = (phx::size(_val) >  0) ] >> attr(logicOr)
                ) 
                >> condition_);

        statement_ = filters_ >> command_;

        start = statement_;
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(condition_)(value_)(strlit_)(regex_)(property_)(statement_)(filters_)(print_)(set_)(command_));
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, statement()          , Skipper> statement_;
    qi::rule<It, std::vector<filter>(), Skipper> filters_;
    qi::rule<It, printcommand()       , Skipper> print_;
    qi::rule<It, setcommand()         , Skipper> set_;
    qi::rule<It, command()            , Skipper> command_;
    qi::rule<It, value()              , Skipper> value_, regex_;
    qi::rule<It, condition()          , Skipper> condition_;
    qi::rule<It, statement()          , Skipper> start;
    // lexemes
    qi::rule<It, std::string()> strlit_, property_; // no skipper
};

bool doParse(std::string const& input)
{
    auto f(begin(input)), l(end(input));

    parser<decltype(f), qi::space_type> p;
    statement parsed;

    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f,l,p,qi::space,parsed);
    if (ok)   
    {
        std::cout << "parse success: '" << input << "'\n";
        generator<boost::spirit::ostream_iterator, karma::space_type> gen;
        std::cout << "parsed: " << karma::format_delimited(gen, karma::space, parsed) << "\n";
    }
    else      
        std::cerr << "parse failed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";

    if (f!=l) 
        std::cerr << "trailing unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";

    return ok;
}

int main()
{
    doParse("where currency like \"GBP|USD\" set logging = 1, logfile = \"myfile\"");
    doParse("where not status = \"ok\" print ident, errorMessage");
    doParse("where status = \"ok\" or not currency like \"GBP|USD\" print ident, errorMessage");
    // All the extra levels of escaping get a bit ugly here. Of course, you'd be reading from a file/database/etc...
    doParse("where status = \"\\\"special\\\"\" set logfile = \"C:\\\\path\\\\to\\\\logfile.txt\"");
}
```

Comment: Fixed a missing brace and made the sample [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16f3ecb19a88e948)