# How to use std::map with boost::phoenix?

Tags: c++, boost, apache-phoenix

How can i use `std::map` inside phoenix lambda function?

```
#include <boost\phoenix.hpp>
#include <map>

int main() {
    using namespace boost::phoenix;
    using namespace boost::phoenix::arg_names;
    using namespace std;
    map<int, int> m;
    auto foo = at(m, 3);
    foo();
}
```

Why it does not work?
I get the following error:

```
C2440   'return': cannot convert from 'int' to 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> ' xxx c:\lib\boost\phoenix\stl\container\container.hpp    167
```

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2015 Community and boost 1.60 library.

Comment: please read this link and post an acceptable code sample: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Now it looks good?

Comment: It probably uses `std::map<int,int>::value_type` to determine the result type, which is a `std::pair<const int,int>`, whereas `std::map<int,int>::at`  just returns a reference to the mapped type, i.e. `int&` or `int const&`.

Comment: Is it possible to fix it? I thought that the phoenix supports all basic `std` containers.

Comment: Specifically [line 160](https://github.com/boostorg/phoenix/blob/boost-1.60.0/include/boost/phoenix/stl/container/container.hpp#L160) or [line 173](https://github.com/boostorg/phoenix/blob/boost-1.60.0/include/boost/phoenix/stl/container/container.hpp#L173). Might be a bug? A template specialization for std::map ought to solve it. Use reference or const_reference instead. Odd that they didn't do that already...

Comment: I don't have time to check at the moment but I think that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14205154/2417774) is similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14205154/2417774) pointed out by [jv_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2417774/jv):

Rather than using the `at` function, use `operator[]`.

```
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::map<int, int> m;
    m[3] = 33;
    auto foo = boost::phoenix::ref(m)[3];
    std::cout << foo() << "\n";
}
```

---

It appears that implementation of the phoenix `at` lazy function uses `value_type` <sup>[[1](https://github.com/boostorg/phoenix/blob/boost-1.60.0/include/boost/phoenix/stl/container/container.hpp#L160)]</sup> <sup>[[2](https://github.com/boostorg/phoenix/blob/boost-1.60.0/include/boost/phoenix/stl/container/container.hpp#L173)]</sup> to determine the result type, which is a `std::pair<const int,int>` in this case. However `std::map<int,int>::at` just returns a `reference` or `const_reference`.

Comment: worth pointing out it has the limitation that it won't work with `cref(m)` because `operator[]` is a non-const operation

Comment: @sehe Good point. Franky I don't get why they implemented it this way, when any `Container` must have `reference` and `const_reference`. But I could be missing something...